# Synchronize Path Iterations in different TFS Projects

Tags: tfs, agile, team-project

We have 6 Team Projects in the Company and we would like to get the iterations in all Projects with the same Start and End date. These iterations don't necessary have the same Name.
By now I have done it manually in the web Interface and tried (without success) to do it with Excel.
Is there a tool or a command which I can use to make this Task easier and faster?

Answer (score 3):

Here you go: http://www.eylean.com/blog/2014/04/unlocking-tfs-potential-with-eylean-board/

This is a TFS two way integration plugin. You could "split" your projects into iterations which have either same or different start and end dates. What's the best, you could actually integrate it to TFS even if you use custom template.

Answer (score 0):

There is no to for this, and you should consider moving everyone into one team project.

There is am API, however you would need to code everything manually.